# Stateless tooltip component using React hooks and ref

Tags: react.js, typescript, jsx

What I'm trying to create is a generic tooltip component that I can use anywhere. I decided on a stateless component and the use of hooks and ref.

**Explanation**

Hook, because I wanted to have a flag for hover and ref to get element width and/or height to center it correctly.

**Problem** ❓

Is this solution correct and will perform fast enough with the bigger amount of tooltip components on the same page (over 100)?
The solutions I've come across so far have not been satisfactory. I wonder if this idea makes a sense if so, I will develop it and publish it as an open source project (I would like to finally make a contribution! )

**Demo:** https://danzawadzki.github.io/react-tooltip/

**Repository:** [https://github.com/danzawadzki/react-tooltip](https://github.com/danzawadzki/react-tooltip/tree/98d9c61a23437e778bb1ce6f80ee39a95fe86509)

**Tooltip.tsx**

```
import * as React from 'react';
import './Tooltip.scss';
import {CSSTransition} from 'react-transition-group';
import {useState} from 'react';
import {useRef} from 'react';

export interface ITooltip {
    /** Tooltip position. */
    position?: 'top' | 'left' | 'right' | 'bottom';
    /** Tooltip message content. */
    message: String;
    /** Array with details about columns to render. */
    children: JSX.Element | Array<JSX.Element> | string;
}

export interface ITooltipStyle {
    /** Distance to the left edge. */
    left?: string;
    /** Distance to the top edge. */
    top?: string;
    /** Distance to the bottom edge. */
    bottom?: string;
    /** Distance to the right edge. */
    right?: string;
}

/**
 * Tooltip component.
 *
 * @author Daniel Zawadzki <hello@danielzawadzki.com>
 * @version 1.0.0
 */
const Tooltip: React.FunctionComponent<ITooltip> = ({position = 'top', message, children}) => {
    /**
     * Hook toggling tooltip isVisible flag.
     */
    const [isVisible, setIsVisible] = useState<boolean>(false);
    const toggle = () => setIsVisible(!isVisible);

    /**
     * Reference to the component to track width and height
     */
    const node = useRef<any>(null);

    /**
     * Positioning the component using the reference
     */
    let style: ITooltipStyle = {};
    if (node.current && node.current.offsetWidth) {
        if (position === 'top' || position === 'bottom') {
            style.left = `${String(node.current.offsetWidth / 2)}px`;
        } else {
            style.top = `-${String(node.current.offsetHeight / 1.5)}px`;
        }
    }

    return (
        <div className="Tooltip">
            <div
                className="Tooltip__toggler"
                onMouseOverCapture={toggle}
                onMouseOut={toggle}
                ref={node}>
                {children}
            </div>
            <CSSTransition
                in={isVisible}
                timeout={200}
                classNames="Tooltip"
                unmountOnExit>
                <div
                    className={`Tooltip__message Tooltip__message--${position}`}
                    style={style}>
                    {message}
                </div>
            </CSSTransition>
        </div>
    );
};

export default Tooltip;
```

I know that there are probably a lot of bugs and areas for development there, but is it any good idea?

Comment: Is it works for dropdown options? I mean there will be no problem with position when scrolling?